# image's sub-image find and replace

Tags: algorithm, image, language-agnostic, image-processing

How can I detect a known image or pattern within an image so that I can replace it with my own text?

Input option 1 (detect aaa and bbb separately):

[image: aaa and bbb are 'slots' where I will place my text]

Input option 2 (detect red value and blue value separately):
[image: Here I use colored rectangles to mark the spaces to fill in]

Output:

[image: what results from the replacement]

Comment: What representation do you have of the pattern you are looking for?

Comment: Do you mean to ask if I can choose what the patterns are?  Yes. I will create the source image.  The molecule comes from another program, but I will manually label where the numbers will go by any means necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Running code

I'll show you the code and results running in [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/) using your option 2.

First we read the image

```
 m = Import@"C:\\imagereplace.png"
```

Then we separate the channels RGB

```
 ColorSeparate[m]
```

Obtaining

[image]

Next we [correlate](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageCorrelate.html) the red channel image (the one to the right) with a Box Matrix, retaining only the rectangular shape. And transform the result to a B&W image.

```
Binarize@ImageCorrelate[m1[[3]], BoxMatrix[3]] ;
```

Obtaining a full size image but containing only the black rectangle.

Now we find the edges of the rectangle (just a loop).

Having the size and coordinates of the rectangles, we create a raster image of the text, corresponding to the detected size, getting:

```
r1 = Binarize@Rasterize["My Text", RasterSize -> {jmax-jmin + 1, imax-imin + 1}, 
                                    ImageSize -> {jmax-jmin + 1, imax- imin + 1}]
```

[image]

Now we replace the data block with the new one. Obtaining:

[image]

I'll not do the Blue channel, as it is the same thing.

HTH!!

Note: The Image correlation is the only trick used. The rest is code as usual. [Here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ConvolutionsAndCorrelations.html) you can find the basics about correlation.